Error when attempting to send automated emails from spreadsheet
I am attempting to send emails collected on a google form. I receive Error:

Failed to send email: no recipient

I am guessing this happens when the script comes to a blank cell that should have email address.
Any help with how I can make sure emails get sent when an invalid email address or blank cell would greatly appreciated.
function sendemails() {


SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").activate();  
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();

var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValue();

for (var i = 3;i<=lr;i++){
      var Student = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var ParentName = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
      var currentEmail2 = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
      var currentEmail3 = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
      var currentEmail4 = ss.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
      var currentEmail5 = ss.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
      var currentEmail6 = ss.getRange(i, 16).getValue();
      var currentEmail7 = ss.getRange(i, 18).getValue();
      var currentEmail8 = ss.getRange(i, 20).getValue();
      var currentEmail9= ss.getRange(i, 22).getValue();
      var currentEmail10 = ss.getRange(i, 24).getValue();


      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{StudentName}",Student).replace("{Parent}", ParentName);
      var subjectLine = "Sweetwater Elementary Light It Up! Fundraiser from " + Student;
      
      
      GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
       GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail2, subjectLine, messageBody); 
       GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail3, subjectLine, messageBody);
        GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail4, subjectLine, messageBody);
         GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail5, subjectLine, messageBody);
          GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail6, subjectLine, messageBody);
           GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail7, subjectLine, messageBody);
            GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail8, subjectLine, messageBody);
             GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail9, subjectLine, messageBody);
               GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail10, subjectLine, messageBody);


      }


Use an if (JavaScript) statement

You should learn the basics of JavaScript, specifically about control flow statements, such as if. You might also learn about comparison operators in JavaScript such as === and !== among other things.

this happens when the script comes to a blank cell that should have email address. One way would be to amend the Google Form and make these questions are "Required" and include validation to ensure that the value is an email.

Related questions :Google Forms Appscript - Skip blank responses and keep adding questions and responses and How do I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?

You want to avoid sending an email when the recipients address was not supplied.
There are several ways of assessing whether an array value (in this case, a recipient email address) exists:

test for a truthy value
test for a blank value

Do NOT test for a "NULL" value since a non-reply in Google Forms does not generate a "Null" (either in the Form response or in the values transmitted to a linked spreadsheet)
Example:
Data array extract: [Wed Sep 11 01:04:28 GMT+10:00 2024, john@example.com, Paul, ]
  if(data[1][3] ){ // truthy
    Logger.log("01:the question was answered = "+data[1][3])
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("01:the question wasn't answered")
  }
  if(data[1][3] != ''){ // blank value
    Logger.log("02:the question was answered = "+data[1][3])
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("02:the question wasn't answered")
  }
  if(data[1][3] != null){ // test for null
    Logger.log("03:the question was answered = "+data[1][3])
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("03:the question wasn't answered")
  }

Results:


01:the question wasn't answered // correct
02:the question wasn't answered // correct
03:the question was answered = // incorrect



So how to process in the script? here's a suggestion
var Student = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
var ParentName = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
var messageBody = templateText.replace("{StudentName}",Student).replace("{Parent}", ParentName);
var subjectLine = "Sweetwater Elementary Light It Up! Fundraiser from " + Student;

// get recipient address, test for truthy and send email
var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
if(currentEmail){ // test for truthy
  Logger.log("the recipient is: "+currentEmail)
  GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
}
else{
  Logger.log("the question wasn't answered; recipient is blank")
}

//Rinse and repeat for each subsequent recipient email address

